# 18.04.1, Threadripper 2, kernel 4.18, RX550 GPU, all up to date, freezes

Tags: kernel, freeze, amd-processor, amdgpu-pro

Is anyone else experiencing freezing with Threadripper 2?

Asus ROG MB with memory from their approved list. 2290wx cpu. Latest bios.
Latest kernel 4.18 patches.

No overclocking. C6 state disabled.
rcu_nocbs=0-63
processor.max_cstate=1
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU=y
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU_ALL=y 
... None of those fix this.

I'm not sure which log to post here to help. faillog doesn't seem to have anything.

I do have this over and over in my syslog

```
 [  846.975579]       Not tainted 4.18.0-041800-generic #201808122131
 [  846.975582] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
 [  846.975585] systemd-udevd   D    0  1050    984 0x80000124
 [  846.975589] Call Trace:
 [  846.975600]  __schedule+0x29e/0x840
 [  846.975603]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
 [  846.975612]  __sev_do_cmd_locked+0x21f/0x290 [ccp]
 [  846.975617]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
 [  846.975622]  sev_do_cmd+0x2f/0x50 [ccp]
 [  846.975624]  ? 0xffffffffc0aba000
 [  846.975629]  sev_get_api_version+0x36/0xa0 [ccp]
 [  846.975634]  ? sp_get_psp_master_device+0x68/0x80 [ccp]
 [  846.975638]  psp_pci_init+0x45/0x230 [ccp]
 [  846.975641]  ? kobject_uevent+0xb/0x10
 [  846.975645]  ? driver_register+0x9e/0xc0
 [  846.975646]  ? 0xffffffffc0aba000
 [  846.975650]  sp_mod_init+0x1a/0x1000 [ccp]
 [  846.975654]  do_one_initcall+0x4a/0x1c4
 [  846.975656]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
 [  846.975660]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xb8/0x1d0
 [  846.975663]  ? do_init_module+0x27/0x220
 [  846.975665]  do_init_module+0x60/0x220
 [  846.975666]  load_module+0x149b/0x1830
 [  846.975670]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbd/0x120
 [  846.975671]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xbd/0x120
 [  846.975674]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
 [  846.975676]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x110
 [  846.975677]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
 [  846.975679] RIP: 0033:0x7fa477ba1839
 [  846.975680] Code: Bad RIP value.
 [  846.975688] RSP: 002b:00007ffd8947f588 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
 [  846.975691] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000560a3694b4b0 RCX: 00007fa477ba1839
 [  846.975692] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fa4778800e5 RDI: 0000000000000007
 [  846.975693] RBP: 00007fa4778800e5 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007ffd8947f6a0
 [  846.975694] R10: 0000000000000007 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
 [  846.975694] R13: 0000560a3693b7c0 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 0000560a3694b4b0
```

Answer (score 0):

By using zenstates.py and turing off cstate 6, I've been running flawlessly for 2 days.